# Cardinality of $Def(X)$

Tags: set-theory

Given any model $\mathfrak{M}=(M,\in)$ of the set theory, we say that a set $Y$ is definable over $\mathfrak{M}$ if there exists $x_0,\cdots, x_m\in M$ such that

$$Y=\{z\in M: \mathfrak{M}\vDash \phi(z,x_0,\cdots, x_m)\}$$

According to the above comment, we define $Def(M)$ as

$$Def(M)=\{Y\subset M: Y \;\text{is definable over}\;\;\mathfrak{M}\}$$

There's a well known result that says if $M$ is infinite then

$$\sharp Def(M)=\sharp M$$

where $\sharp $ denotes cardinality. I want to know where the proof needs the use of choice. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Choice probably only appears in showing that the set of finite tuples $(x_0,\ldots,x_m)$ from $M$ has the same cardinality as $M$.

Comment: @Paul: That actually just gives you a surjection from $M$ onto $\operatorname{Def}(M)$. (I guess we're both thinking about the obvious 'map a class to its definition and parameters')

Comment: Roger, when you say a model of set theory, do you mean that it's a model of $\sf ZF$ or $\sf ZFC$? When you write $(M,\in)$, do you mean it's a standard model, or just that $\in$ is some binary relation on $M$ satisfying the axioms of "set theory" (whichever you mean)?

Comment: Yes. By $\in$ I meant that $(M,\in)$ is a standard model.

Answer (score 0):

For a given formula $\phi$ there are up to $|M^m|$ forms $\phi(z,x_0,...,x_m)$ , and the set of formulae has cardinal $\omega$ (The first infinite ordinal). We want to show that $|S|=|M|$ where $S=\omega \times\cup _{m \in N}( M^m)$. Without AC we do not know that $M$ can be well-ordered and we are stuck. If $M$ can be well-ordered, we can well-order $S$ in the same order-type.Kurt Godel's recursive def'n for $L=\cup_{a\in ON}L_a$, the class of constructible sets, does not use AC because transfinite induction applied to the def'n of  $L_a$ shows that each $L_a$and each $\cup_{b<a}L_b$ can be well-ordered.

Comment: So, do we use AC to ensure that $S$ and $M$ have the same cardinality?

Comment: @Roger: No, you actually don't need the axiom of choice for this here; you use it in the following way, there is a surjection from $S$ onto the definable classes of $M$ (map each formula and parameters to the class it defines), and for getting an injection in the other direction you need the axiom of choice. I'm not entirely convinced that the axiom of choice is *really* needed, but I'm not entirely sure how to show that.

Comment: By "the other direction" do you mean $\sharp M\leq \sharp Def(M)$? I think in that case it's not necesary the use of choice because the map $x\mapsto \{x\}$ is an injective map between $M$ and $Def(M)$.
The other inequality ($\sharp Def(M)\leq \sharp M$) it's easy because the surjection from $S$ onto $Def(M)$ ensures that $\sharp Def(M)\leq \aleph_0\,\sharp M^{<\omega}$ and since $M$ is infinite we have

$$\sharp Def(M)\leq \sharp M$$

I think this proof is correct but I can't see where the choice is needed.

Comment: @Roger: Without assuming the axiom of choice it is consistent that there are $A$ and $B$ with both an injection and a surjection from $A$ to $B$ (as two different functions), but without any bijection between them. When I said the other direction, I had meant an injection that reverses the surjection.

Comment: But, how do you can construct an injection from $Def(M)$ to $S$ only using AC? I mean, AC only ensures that there exists a choice function from $Def(M)$ and $\bigcup Def(M)=M$.

Comment: @Roger: The axiom of choice is equivalent to the statement "If $f\colon A\to B$ is surjective, then there is $g\colon B\to A$ such that $f(g(b))=b$ for all $b\in B$". In particular, if you proved there is a surjection from $M$ onto $\operatorname{Def}(M)$, then the axiom of choice ensures there is an injection that you're looking for.